# How Many Members of Joseph Smith's Council of Fifty Practiced Plural Marriage?

Tags: lds, joseph-smith, polygamy

In March 1844, Joseph Smith organized a special council in the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints known as the [Council of Fifty.](https://www.josephsmithpapers.org/topic/council-of-fifty) Much has been written about the nature and purpose of this organization, which I won't recapitulate here, as that is beyond the scope of my question.

My interest in this council is very specific. I simply want to know how many Council members (and who those members were) that practiced [plural marriage.](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics-essays/plural-marriage-in-the-church-of-jesus-christ-of-latter-day-saints?lang=eng) This includes whether they practiced it in Nauvoo or later. I'm *only* interested in the original members of this Council that were initiated by Joseph Smith during the Nauvoo period, not the ones who were added later after his death.

There are lists of the members of this council at:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_members_of_the_Council_of_Fifty)
- [The Joseph Smith Papers](https://www.josephsmithpapers.org/articles/members-of-council-of-fifty)

  - [PDF version with dates of membership in the Council](https://www.josephsmithpapers.org/bc-jsp/content/jsp/images/content/library/pdf/A1-Chart-Members.pdf)
- [*The Council of Fifty and Its Members, 1844 to 1945* by D. Michael Quinn](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1975&context=byusq)
- [*"It Seems Like Heaven Began on Earth": Joseph Smith and the Constitution of the Kingdom of God* by Andrew F. Ehat](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2027&context=byusq#page=16), extracted from William Clayton's Journal, April 18, 1844.

As far as I know, no one has yet compiled a list which correlates how many members (or what percentage of the members) of the Council of Fifty also practiced plural marriage, either in Nauvoo or later. I would like a list of how many Council members practiced it and what their names were. If anyone has a paper, book, article, etc., which makes this correlation, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there may not be a precise list specific to the council of fifty there are books on polygamy that include names like [Nauvoo Polygamy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007BZ3M2K) (George D. Smith), [More Wives Than One: Transformation of the Mormon Marriage System, 1840–1910](https://www.press.uillinois.edu/books/catalog/55nwm6tk9780252026812.html) (Kathryn M. Daynes), [Identifying the Earliest Mormon Polygamists, 1841-44](https://www.jstor.org/stable/45227374?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) (Gary James Bergera) which mentions **14 of council of fifty in 1844** (48/74), and [Joseph Smith’s Polygamy vol 3](https://gregkofford.com/products/joseph-smiths-polygamy-vol-3-theology) (Brian C. Hales) that I could find.

Below is the list of Council of Fifty from Joseph Smith Papers referenced in OP with a source if there is record of them practicing polygamy:

- Adams, George Washington Joshua (7 Nov. 1810–11 May 1880)
- Babbitt, Almon Whiting (Oct. 1812–Sept. 1856) [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almon_W._Babbitt#:%7E:text=Babbitt%20and%20his%20wife%20Julia,Babbitt%20also%20practiced%20plural%20marriage.) says he did but can find no sources
- Badlam, Alexander, Sr. (28 Nov. 1808–30 Nov./1 Dec. 1894)
- Bent, Samuel (19 July 1778–16 Aug. 1846) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Bernhisel, John Milton (23 June 1799–28 Sept. 1881) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Bonney, Edward William (26 Aug. 1807–4 Feb. 1864)
- Brown, Uriah (9 May 1784–22 Mar. 1853)
- Cahoon, Reynolds (30 Apr. 1790–29 Apr. 1861) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Carrington, Albert (8 Jan. 1813–19 Sept. 1889) [source](https://www.uen.org/utah_history_encyclopedia/c/CARRINGTON_ALBERT.shtml)
- Clayton, William (17 July 1814–4 Dec. 1879) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Coolidge, Joseph Wellington (31 May 1814–13 Jan. 1871) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Cutler, Alpheus (29 Feb. 1784–10 June 1864) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Dana (Denna), Lewis (1 Jan. 1805–8 June 1885)
- Daniels, Cyrus (12 Sept. 1803–before May 1847)
- Dunham, Jonathan (14 Jan. 1800–28 July 1845)
- Eaton, Merinus G. (22 Mar. 1812–?)
- Emmett, James (22 Feb. 1803–28 Dec. 1852)
- Farnham, John W. (5/15 Dec. 1794–16 Aug. 1846)
- Fielding, Amos (16 July 1792–5 Aug. 1875) [source](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/17316845/amos-fielding)
- Fielding, Joseph (26 Mar. 1797–19 Dec. 1863) - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Fielding), says it's also documented in his personal diary
- Foster, Lucian Rose (12 Nov. 1806–19 Mar. 1876) [maybe?](https://www.josephsmithpapers.org/person/lucian-rose-foster) - married four times, not sure if successively or polygamously
- Fullmer, David (7 July 1803–21 Oct. 1879) [source pg 152 (30/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Fullmer, John Solomon (21 July 1807–8 Oct. 1883) [source](https://familypedia.wikia.org/wiki/John_Solomon_Fullmer_(1807-1883)#Marriage_.26_Family) another [source](https://history.churchofjesuschrist.org/overlandtravel/pioneers/3485/john-solomon-fullmer)
- Grant, George Davis (10 Sept. 1812–20 Sept. 1876)
- Grant, Jedediah Morgan (21 Feb. 1816–1 Dec. 1856) [source](http://signaturebookslibrary.org/susa-young-gates/)
- Greene, John Portineus (3 Sept. 1793–10 Sept. 1844) [maybe](https://www.josephsmithpapers.org/person/john-portineus-greene) - can't tell if first wife died/divorced
- Haws, Peter (17 Feb. 1796–1862) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Heywood, Joseph L. (1 Aug. 1815–16 Oct. 1910) [source](https://snaccooperative.org/ark:/99166/w6862q18)
- Hollister, David Sprague (4 June 1808–after 3 Oct. 1851)
- Hyde, Orson (8 Jan. 1805–28 Nov. 1878) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- James, Samuel (18 Jan. 1806–after 1880)
- Johnson, Benjamin F. (28 July 1818–18 Nov. 1905) [source pg 153 (31/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Kimball, Heber Chase (14 June 1801–22 June 1868) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Lee, John Doyle (6 Sept. 1812–23 Mar. 1877) [source  pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Lewis, Philip Bessom (16 Jan. 1804–13 Nov. 1877) [source](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1021&context=mormonhistory)
- Lott, Cornelius Peter (27 Sept. 1798–6 July 1850) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Lyman, Amasa Mason (30 Mar. 1813–4 Feb. 1877) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Marks, William (15 Nov. 1792–22 May 1872)
- Miller, George (25 Nov. 1794–after July 1856) [source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43200579), [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Miller_(Latter_Day_Saints)#Marriages), [also mentioned in a biography of Lyman Wight](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=6211&context=etd#page=105)
- Miller, Henry William (1 May 1807–9 Oct. 1885) [source](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/108011/henry-william-miller)
- Morley, Isaac (11 Mar. 1786–24 June 1865) [source pg 150 (28/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Pack, John (20 May 1809–4 Apr. 1885) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Page, John Edward (25 Feb. 1799–14 Oct. 1867) [maybe](https://mormonstudies.as.virginia.edu/research/the-early-mormon-marriage-database/person/?id=32979)
- Parker, John Davis (22 Nov. 1799–26 Feb. 1891) [source pg 152 (30/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Phelps, William Wines (17 Feb. 1792–7 Mar. 1872) [source pg 152 (30/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Pratt, Orson (19 Sept. 1811–3 Oct. 1881) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Pratt, Parley Parker (12 Apr. 1807–13 May 1857) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Rich, Charles Coulson (21 Aug. 1809–17 Nov. 1883) [source pg 142 (20/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Richards, Levi (14 Apr. 1799–18 June 1876) [source](https://familypedia.wikia.org/wiki/Levi_Willard_Richards_(1845-1914))
- Richards, Willard (24 June 1804–11 Mar. 1854) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Rigdon, Sidney (19 Feb. 1793–14 July 1876)
- Rockwell, Orrin Porter (June 1814–9 June 1878) [source pg 142-149](https://archive.org/details/orrinporterrockw00schi/page/142/mode/2up?view=theater) (quasi, briefly; the relationship only lasted a few months)
- Rockwood, Albert Perry (9 June 1805–25 Nov. 1879) [source pg 153 (31/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Roundy, Shadrach (1 Jan. 1789–4 July 1872)
- Shumway, Charles (2 Aug. 1806–21 May 1898) [source](https://www.latterdaylight.com/question-of-the-day/2019/2/6/charles-shumway)
- Smith, Elias (6 Sept. 1804–24 June 1888) [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_Smith_(Mormon)) says he did but can find no sources
- Smith, George Albert (26 June 1817–1 Sept. 1875) [source pg 142 (20/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Smith, Hyrum (9 Feb. 1800–27 June 1844) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Smith, John (16 July 1781–23 May 1854) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Smith, Joseph (23 Dec. 1805–27 June 1844) [source](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics-essays/plural-marriage-in-kirtland-and-nauvoo?lang=eng)
- Smith, William B. (13 Mar. 1811–13 Nov. 1893) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Snow, Erastus (9 Nov. 1818–27 May 1888) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Spencer, Daniel (20 July 1794–8 Dec. 1868) [source?](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23288624)
- Spencer, Orson (14 Mar./13 May 1802–15 Oct. 1855) [source](https://www.uen.org/utah_history_encyclopedia/s/SPENCER_ORSON.shtml)
- Taylor, John (1 Nov. 1808–25 July 1887) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Thayer, Ezra (14 Oct. 1791–6 Sept. 1862)
- Turley, Theodore (10 Apr. 1801–12 Aug. 1871) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Wasson, Lorenzo D. (1819–28 July 1857)
- Whitney, Newel Kimball (3/5 Feb. 1795–23 Sept. 1850) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Wight, Lyman (9 May 1796–31 Mar. 1858) [source](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/usupress_pubs/43/), [source](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=6211&context=etd#page=107)
- Woodruff, Wilford (1 Mar. 1807–2 Sept. 1898) [source](https://archive.sltrib.com/article.php?id=2626102&itype=CMSID)
- Woodworth, Lucien (3 Apr. 1799–after 1860)
- Yearsley, David D. (3 Mar. 1808–Oct. 1849) [source?](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/46476556/david-dutton-yearsley) - uncertain
- Young, Brigham (1 June 1801–29 Aug. 1877) [source pg 135 (13/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Young, Joseph (7 Apr. 1797–16 July 1881) [source pg 151 (29/36)](https://www.dialoguejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/sbi/articles/Dialogue_V34N0102_135.pdf)
- Young, Phineas Howe (16 Feb. 1799–10 Oct. 1879) [source](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/32067042/phineas-howe-young)

Comment: Thanks for putting this together! I've suggested an edit which adds a few more sources for some individuals and corrected a few mistakes. If you accept it, I'd be happy to accept your answer :-)

Comment: @GDP2 thanks for those addition sources